# tail -f | awk and end tail once data is found

Tags: awk, pipe, tail

I am trying to build a script which `tail -f | awk` the log file which is getting updated every second. awk part will fetch me only the required part of the log file based on my search parameter. Output XML is also captured in an output file. Script is working fine - as expected.

Issue - However ever after the search is performed it stays hung due to `tail -f`. Any idea how to update below script - so that once the output XML is captured, it should break the tail part??

```
XMLF=/appl/logs/abc.log

aa_pam=${1-xml}
[[ ${2-xml} = "xml" ]] && tof=xml_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).xml || tof=$2
tail -f $XMLF | \
awk  ' BEGIN { Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1; i=0}
       /\<\?xml version\=/ { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line,i)
                             Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1;
       }
       { Trap_arry[Cnt_line++]=$0;
       }
       /'${1-xml}'/ { Print_SW=1;
       }
       /\<\/XYZ_999/    { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i);
                             Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1; }
       END { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i); }
function p_out(Cnt_Line, i) {
       for (i=1;i<Cnt_line;i++) {print Trap_arry[i] | "tee '$tof'" }
}
' | tee $tof
```

***Update*** Tried as per below suggestion of using `exit` - it is existing the script successfully - however the xml that is getting captured at output is getting duplicated. So in the output file - same XML appears twice..!!

```
XMLF=/appl/logs/abc.log

aa_pam=${1-xml}
[[ ${2-xml} = "xml" ]] && tof=xml_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).xml || tof=$2
tail -f $XMLF | \
awk  ' BEGIN { Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1; i=0}
       /\<\?xml version\=/ { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line,i)
                             Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1;
       }
       { Trap_arry[Cnt_line++]=$0;
       }
       /'${1-xml}'/ { Print_SW=1;
       }
       /\<\/XYZ_999/    { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i);
                             Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1; }
       END { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i); }
function p_out(Cnt_Line, i) {
       for (i=1;i<Cnt_line;i++) {print Trap_arry[i] | "tee '$tof'" } { exit }
}
' | tee $tof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this question [How to break a tail -f command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515372/how-to-break-a-tail-f-command-in-bash) you could try

```
#! /bin/bash

XMLF=/appl/logs/abc.log

aa_pam=${1-xml}
[[ ${2-xml} = "xml" ]] && tof=xml_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).xml || tof=$2

mkfifo log.pipe
tail -f "$XMLF" > log.pipe & tail_pid=$!

awk  -vpar1="$aa_pam" -vtof="$tof" -f t.awk  < log.pipe
kill $tail_pid
rm log.pipe
```

where `t.awk` is:

```
/<\?xml version\=/ {
    if (Print_SW==1) {
        p_out(Cnt_Line)
    }
    Print_SW=0
    Cnt_line=0
}

{
    Trap_arry[++Cnt_line]=$0
}

$0 ~ par1 {
    Print_SW=1;
}

/<\/XYZ_999/    {
    if (Print_SW==1)
        p_out(Cnt_Line)
    Print_SW=0
    Cnt_line=0
}

function p_out(Cnt_Line, i) {
    for (i=1; i<Cnt_line; i++) {
        print Trap_arry[i] | ("tee " tof)
    }
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: tried as per your suggestion - and it worked nicely..!!  Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: I just observed, that the end tag value </XYZ_999> is not getting captured in the output file. Can you please guide how to fix it?

Comment: I got it.. had to replace /<\/XYZ_999/ to /<\/XYZ_999>/

Answer (score 2):

Call `exit` (which will jump to your `END` block prior to termination) after you are finished capturing your output.

When awk terminates, the next `write()` to stdout by `tail -f` will result in an `EPIPE` error. tail knows to terminate when that happens.

UPDATE: You seem to be having some problem trying to decide where to put the exit. It should not be in `p_out` because you call `p_out` from both the closing XML tag match expression *and* from the `END` block. Try this instead:

```
XMLF=/appl/logs/abc.log

aa_pam=${1-xml}
[[ ${2-xml} = "xml" ]] && tof=xml_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).xml || tof=$2
tail -f $XMLF | \
awk  '
  BEGIN {
    Print_SW=0
    Cnt_line=1
    i=0
  }

  /\<\?xml version\=/ {
     if (Print_SW==1)
        p_out(Cnt_Line,i)
     Print_SW=0
     Cnt_line=1
  }

  {
    Trap_arry[Cnt_line++]=$0
  }

  /'${1-xml}'/ {
    Print_SW=1;
  }

  /\<\/XYZ_999/ {
    if (Print_SW==1)
      p_out(Cnt_Line, i)
    Print_SW=0
    Cnt_line=1
    exit
  }

  END {
    if (Print_SW==1)
      p_out(Cnt_Line, i);
  }

  function p_out(Cnt_Line, i) {
    for (i=1;i<Cnt_line;i++) {
      print Trap_arry[i] | "tee '$tof'"
    }
  }
' | tee $tof
```

Comment: I tried added { exit } as shown below - but it is not waiting for the tail -f and awk to perform the search - it is breaking up directly.

       { Trap_arry[Cnt_line++]=$0;
       }
       /'${1-xml}'/ { Print_SW=1;
       }
       /\<\/XYZ_999/    { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i);
                             Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1; } { exit }
       END { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i); }
function p_out(Cnt_Line, i) {
       for (i=1;i<Cnt_line;i++) {print Trap_arry[i] | "tee '$tof'" }
}
' | tee $tof

Comment: You have `exit` in a block of its own. Any block which is not tied to an expression is evaluated once per line of input, meaning you're exiting immediately after the first line has been read. Try moving the `exit` into the block where you're processing the XML's closing tag.

Comment: okk, I will remove the `exit` block as suggested, but can you please guide how to implement your original response in the script? Not sure at which place exactly the change is required.

Comment: After the `Cnt_line=1;` in the preceding block.

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion - however the script gets ended without doing anything. It doesn't wait as well for the record to come in (`tail -f` part) and so no output XML is getting capture.

Comment: I tried with exactly same script that you gave, but its still instead of it waiting for any entry in log file - it simply exists without doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could, in the awk script, add a line such as:

```
/some-end-of-xml-marker/  {  close(/dev/stdin) ; }
```

I didn't try it, but you get the idea: close STDIN when you reached the end of the file, so that the loop in awk stops and you get to the END part (not tested, I hope this proves to be correct...)

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion - added `{  close(/dev/stdin) ; }` but still it is not breaking up the tail -f | awk part after successful search - I have added it as below `/\<\/XYZ_999/    { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i);
                             Print_SW=0; Cnt_line=1; } {  close(/dev/stdin) ; }
       END { if (Print_SW==1) p_out(Cnt_Line, i); }
function p_out(Cnt_Line, i) {
       for (i=1;i<Cnt_line;i++) {print Trap_arry[i] | "tee '$tof'" }`