# How to break a tail -f command in bash

Tags: bash

How can I break a `tail -f` in bash? Since this question is related to this question

[tail -f | awk and end tail once data is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500685/tail-f-awk-and-end-tail-once-data-is-found)

I tried the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

tvar="testing"
(set -o pipefail && tail -f <<< "$tvar" | awk '{print; exit} END{ exit 1}'  )
```

But the script is still hanging on to `tail -f`

Comment: Can you try [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the problem is not the `tail -f` but the `awk` which hangs.  It is meant to terminate when EOF is found (with `exit 1`).  But there is no EOF found; the `tail -f` does not terminate, so there comes no EOF.

Would the `awk` terminate, then this would also break the pipe and the `tail` would receive a SIGPIPE (which would terminate it).

You must find a different condition on which to terminate.

EDIT:

To achieve what you want you can start the `tail -f` in the background, remember its PID and kill it as soon as you do not need it anymore.  Running in the background and using a pipe at the same time is tricky.  The easiest way to do it would be to use a named pipe (FIFO):

```
mkfifo log.pipe
tail -f log > log.pipe & tail_pid=$!
awk ... < log.pipe
kill $tail_pid
rm log.pipe
```

Comment: I added an `exit` statement, see update. `awk` now enters the `END` clause and should exit. But the scripts is still hanging..

Comment: Yeah, because _your_ `tail -f` is strange in the aspect that it does not write anything anymore.  It would terminate as soon as it tries to write something into the closed pipe.  But since this strange case of using `tail -f` to print a variable obviously isn't your _real_ usecase, maybe you could tell us a little more about what you originally tried to achieve.

Comment: Yes it is related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500685/tail-f-awk-and-end-tail-once-data-is-found

Comment: I added another approach to my answer.  I don't really like using named pipes, but in this case it might be appropriate.

Comment: Yes this might be a solution.. But I tried it now with the `log` file open in an editor at the same time. The script works, but the editor now hangs..

Comment: But surely a hanging editor is not the topic of this question ;-)

Comment: I would like to add a line of text in the editor and save it, and see if the `tail -f` outputs this to the `awk` program..

Comment: Use `date >> file` for appending a line.  Your editor might do strange things like renaming the original file to create a backup and write the file anew etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that switching from using `<<<` to `echo "$tvar" | tail -f` does what you want instead?

```
$> cat test.sh
#! /bin/bash

tvar="testing"
(set -o pipefail && echo "$tvar" | tail -f | awk '{print} END{ exit 1}'  )
$> ./test.sh
testing
$>
```

Although the awk doesn't print anything out afterwards.

Comment: Yes this works, but it does not work if `tail -f ` reads from a file. For example `tail -f file.txt | awk ..` does not work..

Comment: I agree but this comes back to the point @alfe made above - there is no EOF received by tail to exit. Therefore it sits waiting for more input from the file forever.